# scaling UIScrollView contentSize to fit UIView with variable-height UITableView inside

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a uiview with a uiscrollview as a subview in a nib. 
Then, I load another uiview with a uitableview as a subview of this other uiview (among other elements inside this view) as a subview of the uiscrollview.

That is, UISCrollView -> UIView -> UITableView (and some other views inside the UIView).

And I need to do the following:

Once I know the final height of the tableview (depending on the number of cells and height of them) I need to resize the uiview containing it and, in turn, resize the contentSize property of the containing scrollview.

But I don't know at which point the final size of the tableview is known (because it can dynamically change size depending on the amount of text its cells will hold) and neither do I know by how much will the tableview exceed the uiview (which by default is 320 x 460).

I've tried setting the view containing the tableview to a height of 900 on viewdidload and setting it to sizeToFit, hoping it would shrink as tablecells are added to the tableview (assuming as cells are added the tableview's frame would scale appropriately). But this doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into a similar situation (UIScrollView -> UITableView) and was banging my head against it for hours. The short answer is this: the correct sizes to use as the basis of sizing things out were not available until my ViewController (governing the UIScrollView) was sent `viewWillAppear:`.  Before then, I found that the values were set, but often wrong.  (E.g., my first attempt at doing this was in `viewDidLoad:`, and the sizing values *were* changed there, but they were *wrong*!)

So my solution was thus:

- In `viewDidLoad:` cause your enclosed UITableView to `reloadData` once you have your data in place.
- in `viewWillAppear:` do the following (presuming `tableView` is the enclosed UITableView and `scrollView` is the enclosing UIScrollView):

  ```
  tableView.frame = (CGRect){ 
      tableView.frame.origin,
      tableView.contentSize 
  };
  // Finally, set content size based on the last element in the scrollView
  // in my case, the last element IS the tableView, yours might be different
  scrollView.contentSize = 
      CGSizeMake(scrollView.width 
                 - scrollView.contentInset.left
                 - self.scrollView.contentInset.right,
                 tableView.top
                 + tableView.height);
  ```

N.B., I was getting some very weird numbers when I checked them before `viewWillAppear:`; e.g., the tableView.contentSize seemed to be the product of default rowHeight * number of rows, ignoring my custom row heights and excluding any separators! Very odd.

Comment: Your answer saved me my home time. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but since UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, can you use the contentSize property to see its overall size after a call to reloadData?  You could use the size of the tableview to resize the UIView and the contentSize of the scrollView.

Comment: I might give it a try that way. Though, where should I make the call to reload data? I mean, I'm pretty sure the sequence of method calls are: viewDidLoad -> numberOfSectionsInTableView -> numberOfRowsInSection -> cellForRowAtIndexPath. At this point, the tableview is done being built. So where should I place now the call to reloadData? Or does it get called by default after the call chain I just mentioned?

Comment: Hmmm...I admit that I am not completely sure at which point of the loading process a table view is filled, but are you sure it comes after viewDidLoad?  I think that if you called reloadData *inside of* viewDidLoad and then check the contentSize right afterwards, that it will be the correct value.