# is UIScrollView or a UIWebView the better solution for this?

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, uiscrollview, instagram

I am spec'ing out an iOS app and there is a piece that is a run-on section that will need to scroll. I was thinking of doing it as a UIScrollView (have never used one but seems logical) but it sounds like the contentSize always needs to be calculated. This could be extremely variable in this case (UGC images etc...). Is this correct? Or is there a legitimate workaround? If not, would a UIWebView be the better solution?

The app functionality would be like a FB feed or Instagram. Is it known what they use (FB looks like UIWebView to me).

thx

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you use the web view you will have to generate html code to feed it and if you have buttons, you probably have to generate more html/css/js to make everything work. Using the scroll view is not a pain... Calculating the content size is easy... All your elements' height + some offset between them. Its bounds will remain always the same, you should only set the content size.

Comment: Re content size, most of the examples I see use only images. We would have a lot of text that would be brought in via apis. So it wouldn't be a fixed site. Also, I'd imagine people do lazy loading with UIScrollView's. If yes, you woudn't know the size. Is there a potential workaround for this? Or is this sounding like I should be doing a UIWebView?

Comment: You can calculate and change the content size dynamically, and even more by getting the scroll position of the scroll view you can request more data on demand from the api. It's just, new data arrives increase the contentSize.height + 100p for ex...

Comment: ok - this seems relavant to what we're discussing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508517/scaling-uiscrollview-contentsize-to-fit-uiview-with-variable-height-uitableview  . But like in the original question, I'm thinking a little bit more of building out a UIScrollView similar to Instagram feed.   Re your above comment, is the model you're suggesting the following: Build like the first 1000 pixels of content and make it fixed for only vertical scrolling. Since the user can only scroll down, when the user is scrolling down capture the contentOffset and then adding to contentSize.height?cont

Comment: In what function do you add this functionality? Is there a way to observe the contentOffset property? Would you use KVO or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience , I have the client-side web application development experience before iOS development .For the first time, I though `UIWebView` is pretty easier than `UIScrollView` because I can handle `html/css/javascript` as my wish.

But I found some problem with `UIWebView` Performance. If you have complex functional usability and large amount of data loading. So I try to implement with `UIScrollView`, Of course, It's quite not easy for me to create complex View with `UIScrollView` but when I've been familiar with the implement instruction. I think `UIScrollView` have a better performance then `UIWebView` ,especially complex layout and usability.

I recommend you to use both of them base on situation.

For some simply ViewController that just display an information with less complicate use, `UIWebView` is fine if you have familiar client-side web application development.

For some complex usability, It may not easy to implement with `UIScrollView` but It's quite OK for performance issue.

Comment: thx for answer - i agree with most of what you're saying - this is a little bit the dilemna of where I'm at. It sounds like to make UIScrollView to work in a complex layout and handle issues like a paragraph or two of text will be difficult.

Comment: By the way, you can also look "Three20" project http://three20.info/. you may find what you need.

Comment: have looked at Three20 - since we've already started work. I don't think it's right. Maybe if we used it from scratch.